# R Import json list as dataset

Tags: r, json, dataframe, import

I am trying to import a json as a dataframe, but it imports as a list. I have tried other threads' solutions, but they are not working in my case.

What I want to import is a dataframe with six columns: unix, low, high, open, close and volume. The json is also structured in this way. The code is below:

```
library(rjson)

json_file <- "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-usd/candles?granularity=86400"
json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)

json_data <- setNames(stack(fromJSON(file=json_data))[6:1],c('unix', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'volume'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tidyverse and jsonlite, try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

json_file <- "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/btc-usd/candles?granularity=86400"
json_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = json_file, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) %>% as_tibble()
colnames(json_data) <- c('unix', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'volume')

json_data
# A tibble: 300 x 6
         unix    low   high   open  close volume
        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1619136000 47465. 52131. 51696. 49837. 28055.
 2 1619049600 50400  55470. 53796. 51702. 30428.
 3 1618963200 53621. 56811. 56478. 53801. 15584.
 4 1618876800 53430. 57111  55697. 56499. 18608.
 5 1618790400 54188. 57600  56274. 55697. 16838.
 6 1618704000 51300  60438. 60067. 56274. 36892.
 7 1618617600 59700  62572. 61427. 60059. 10848.
 8 1618531200 60048. 63604. 63229. 61427. 19867.
 9 1618444800 62037. 63832. 62972. 63229. 11209.
10 1618358400 61278. 64899  63588. 62972. 22571.
# ... with 290 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to stick with `rjson` you can try this

```
df<- t(sapply(json_data, function(x) unlist(x)))
colnames(df) <- c("unix", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume")

> df
             unix      low     high     open    close     volume
  [1,] 1619136000 47464.65 52130.58 51695.98 49641.26  28219.029
  [2,] 1619049600 50400.00 55469.98 53795.62 51701.59  30427.892
  [3,] 1618963200 53620.91 56810.56 56477.67 53800.86  15584.084
  [4,] 1618876800 53430.01 57111.00 55696.83 56499.29  18608.280
  [5,] 1618790400 54187.85 57600.00 56273.65 55696.83  16838.392
  [6,] 1618704000 51300.00 60437.97 60067.20 56274.41  36891.710
  [7,] 1618617600 59700.00 62572.48 61427.27 60058.86  10847.768
  [8,] 1618531200 60048.43 63604.34 63229.04 61427.27  19867.413
  [9,] 1618444800 62036.73 63831.82 62971.80 63229.04  11209.451
```